# parse error in test cases string: unexpected escaped character

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-agent, squish

I am trying to run my squish test on slave machine (windows) using Jenkins from master machine (windows).

When I tried to run test case from squish IDE from slave machine it is working fine. Same when I am trying to run from remote machine (master jenkins machine) I am getting this error :

**>> Exception: parse error in test cases string: unexpected escaped character**

Also in my console output , **under squish configuration in slave I am getting IP address of my master machine rather than slave machine** , where I want to run the test case.

Comment: I don't really follow ... because you didn't input too many details. I also use Squish, and run tests from a linux server, inside a Windows VM (that also runs inside the server). I do this trough some python scripts. If its your case, maybe I can help you, If not, it would really help if you have a logic in your problem and enter more details. Maybe someone else can help you.

Comment: @iugene My task is to integrate squish with jenkins, where squish will be installed on a slave machine and I have to execute the test cases in squish from jenkins master machine on network. Now as I have integrated both as per the documentation found over net and trying to run the job from jenkins master machine then on console of jenkins machine I am getting this error >> >> Exception: parse error in test cases string: unexpected escaped character <<. And when trying to run the test case from squish IDE on slave machine it is working fine.